# Adding Authorization Header for Token Into Spring

Tags: java, spring, api, authentication, http-headers

I'm new to the Spring framework and I'm creating an API for a social media application. I'm familiar with creating requests but I'm now after adding a bit of security.

I've programmed the application to generate an auth token on signup or login and I would like to add the Authorization Header to each and every request I choose it for. (Is this possible?)

Example:

- Login Request: Authentication Header **Not** **Required**
- Search Request: Authentication Header **Required**

I plan on making a function to check that the authentication token provided matches the user requesting but I've been on the hunt everywhere for finding a solution to simply check that the Authentication Header has been added in the request.

If it hasn't been added it should return an unauthorized HTTP response and likewise if the auth token isn't valid (which I will handle).

Can anyone shed some light on this for a newbie?